# How to incorporate `pooch` with scipy.datasets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scipy

I am trying to use the `ascent` image data from `scipy.datasets`. My code on the Jupyter Notebook:

```
import scipy.datasets
import pooch
!pip show pooch
ascent = scipy.datasets.ascent()
ascent.shape
```

When I run this, I find a version of has been successfully installed but at the same time, it throws an ImportError!

What is wrong? Have I installed the wrong version? Or is there something more that I need to do?

```
Name: pooch
Version: 1.7.0
Summary: "Pooch manages your Python library's sample data files: it automatically downloads and stores them in a local directory, with support for versioning and corruption checks."
Home-page: https://github.com/fatiando/pooch
Author: The Pooch Developers
Author-email: fatiandoaterra@protonmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: packaging, platformdirs, requests
Required-by: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 4
      2 import pooch
      3 get_ipython().system('pip show pooch')
----> 4 ascent = scipy.datasets.ascent()
      5 ascent.shape

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/datasets/_fetchers.py:71, in ascent()
     66 import pickle
     68 # The file will be downloaded automatically the first time this is run,
     69 # returning the path to the downloaded file. Afterwards, Pooch finds
     70 # it in the local cache and doesn't repeat the download.
---> 71 fname = fetch_data("ascent.dat")
     72 # Now we just need to load it with our standard Python tools.
     73 with open(fname, 'rb') as f:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/datasets/_fetchers.py:27, in fetch_data(dataset_name, data_fetcher)
     25 def fetch_data(dataset_name, data_fetcher=data_fetcher):
     26     if data_fetcher is None:
---> 27         raise ImportError("Missing optional dependency 'pooch' required "
     28                           "for scipy.datasets module. Please use pip or "
     29                           "conda to install 'pooch'.")
     30     # The "fetch" method returns the full path to the downloaded data file.
     31     return data_fetcher.fetch(dataset_name)

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pooch' required for scipy.datasets module. Please use pip or conda to install 'pooch'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: restart Python.

Long answer: normally, installing a package is enough to be able to import it, even if Python was started before the package was installed. However, once Python has successfully imported a package, it will not re-import the same package for the duration of the Python process.

Within SciPy, the way they import Pooch is this code:

```
try:
    import pooch
except ImportError:
    pooch = None
    data_fetcher = None
```

([Source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.3/scipy/datasets/_fetchers.py#L4-L8).)

Since `data_fetcher` is None, the error you see is triggered:

```
File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/datasets/_fetchers.py:27, in fetch_data(dataset_name, data_fetcher)
     25 def fetch_data(dataset_name, data_fetcher=data_fetcher):
     26     if data_fetcher is None:
---> 27         raise ImportError("Missing optional ...
```

This means that SciPy will not attempt to re-import Pooch if it has failed once. Since SciPy has been "successfully" loaded, Python will not attempt to re-import SciPy either.

To solve this, restart Python.